# MMS delivery report

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-s-3, mms

I have GT-I9300 and JB 4.1.2.

Until now, I thought that my MMS' weren't delivered. But now I've noticed that people are actually getting my MMS' but I don't receive the delivery report. How is that possible?

Btw, I have the delivery report setting checked for both SMS and MMS.

Comment: Could be that your provider ignores them? As far as I know, those "delivery reports" don't get answered by the recipient, but by the network carrying the message to its target. It's not the same as a "return receipt request" used for mail, but rather like the "delivery report" there (the former gets answered by the recipient, the latter by the mail server).

Comment: Ok, I'll look into my provider.

Comment: I’m coming late here, but it’s quite the contrary : MMS delivery reports are done by the user terminal, not the provider, contrary to what’s the case with SMSes. Nowadays, it seems iPhones don’t honor requests for delivery reports, and it has been so for a long time. I guess poor implementation of the traditional messaging system is a way to force people into iMessages, which is a bad thing if you ask me. That being said, I fear Android considers going the same way…